# Celery Retry not working on AWS Beanstalk running Docker ver.1.6.2(Multi container)

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, celery

Am trying to implement retries in one of my celery tasks which works fine on my local development environment but doesn't execute retries when deployed to AWS beanstalk.

Comment: can you give more details - is there an error or traceback? can you show some excerpts from logs etc that show task failing but not being retried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Knoob mistake:

Turns out that I had another environment with similar code consuming from the same rabbitMQ server. Seems this other environment was picking up the retries.